# Nesting PHP If loops

Tags: php, if-statement, nested

So I'm trying to validate an Address form field and a P.O. Box form field. So far I have this:

```
if (empty($_POST["po"]) && empty($_POST["address"]))
{
    $poErr = "Please enter a P.O. Number OR address";
    $addressErr = "Please enter a P.O. Number OR address";
    if (!preg_match("/[0-9]{1,}$/",$po))
    {
        $po = test_input($_POST["po"]);
        $poErr = "Please enter only a number for P.O. Box.";
    }
    if (!preg_match("([0-9]{1,} [\s\S]*?)",$address))
    {
        $address = test_input($_POST["address"]);
        $addressErr = "Address must be only letters, numbers or one of the following _ - . , : ' \"";
    }
}
```

The `test_input` just checks special chars.

What I want to do is see if P.O. Box and Address is empty, if it is, then I will tell it to display an error into html to enter a value for one field or the other, which turns out fine. What I want to do after that is to determine which one is filled, and then verify one and/or both fields if one, or  both happen to be filled.

Here is my HTML where I want the "po" and "address" values to remain if there were to be another error on the form:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="address">Your Mailing Address **</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="address" id="address" placeholder="Your Mailing Address" value="<?php echo $address; ?>">
        <br /><span class="error"><?php echo $addressErr; ?></span>
    </div><!--form group address-->

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="po">Your P.O. Box (Number only) **</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="po" id="po" placeholder="#" value="<?php echo $po; ?>">
        <br /><span class="error"><?php echo $poErr; ?></span>
    </div><!--form group address-->
```

Comment: Can you please mention error which you are facing. please make sure in `$po` and `$address` you are getting correct value.

Comment: To be clear, the only error is when the form fields are not filled. I am not acquiring my desired result with this code. I am just not able to nest the ifs appropriately to determine if one or both fields are filled and to verify the field(s) that are filled. 

When I test to make sure that both fields are empty, that is the only part of the code that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition is wrong. if both fields empty then you write check for individual fields.
if both fields empty then it will goes inside that condition. and also you want to keep value if error in form then change `$po` to `$_POST['po']` and `$address` to `$_POST['address']`

```
$poErr = $addressErr = '';
if (empty($_POST["po"]) && empty($_POST["address"])) {
    $poErr = "Please enter a P.O. Number OR address";
    $addressErr = "Please enter a P.O. Number OR address";
} else {
    if (!empty($_POST["po"]) && !preg_match("/[0-9]{1,}$/", $_POST["po"])) {
        $po = test_input($_POST["po"]);
        $poErr = "Please enter only a number for P.O. Box.";
    }
    if (!empty($_POST["address"]) && !preg_match("([0-9]{1,} [\s\S]*?)", $_POST["address"])) {
        $address = test_input($_POST["address"]);
        $addressErr = "Address must be only letters, numbers or one of the following _ - . , : ' \"";
    }
}
```

After form submission you want keep value in form , please change below fields:-

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="address" id="address" placeholder="Your Mailing Address" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST["address"])) ? $_POST["address"] : ''; ?>">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="po" id="po" placeholder="#" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST["po"])) ? $_POST["po"] : ''; ?>">
```

Comment: This is the closest that I've been looking for though. Placing incorrect values flags the correct error for each field.

Comment: Sorry -- When entering a correct value, the "Please enter a P.O. Number OR address" error shows, when it should have no errors.

Comment: Everything works perfectly, the only problem now is that the value doesn't stay after submitting the form with another error on the form (done on purpose for test sake).

Comment: After submitting form where you want to keep value. in the same text fields?

Comment: Right. I updated my post to show where I want the values to stay if there were to be another error on the form.

Comment: I know I was able to keep the value at some point during this process, but currently every other form element stays when I have the test error besides the address and PO box.

Comment: It works perfectly! It keeps the value after submission while there is still an error. Thank you so much! :D

Answer (score 1):

if both fields are empty it will be in first condition and if any of the fields is not empty it will be handled in else part like below.

```
if (empty($_POST["po"]) && empty($_POST["address"]))
{
    $poErr = "Please enter a P.O. Number OR address";
    $addressErr = "Please enter a P.O. Number OR address";
}else {

    if (!preg_match("/[0-9]{1,}$/",$_POST["po"]))
    {
        $po = test_input($_POST["po"]);
        $poErr = "Please enter only a number for P.O. Box.";
    }
    if (!preg_match("([0-9]{1,} [\s\S]*?)",$_POST["address"]))
    {
        $address = test_input($_POST["address"]);
        $addressErr = "Address must be only letters, numbers or one of the following _ - . , : ' \"";
    }
}
```

Comment: When I enter invalid text into the field (based on regex), it throws the error code into the HTML for both address and po box. I was hoping that it would be able to see which one is filled, and then validate that field (or both if they are both filled).

Comment: may be you have provided empty input to `preg_match` change `$po` to `$_POST["po"]`

Answer (score 0):

you need to user

```
if($_POST["po"]=='')
```

this might help you

and you can also change the structure like

```
if ($_POST['po']=='' && $_POST['address']=='')
{
     echo $poErr = "Please enter a P.O. Number OR address";
     echo $addressErr = "Please enter a P.O. Number OR address";
}
else
{
        if (!preg_match("/[0-9]{1,}$/",$po))
        {
            echo  $po = test_input($_POST["po"]);
            echo  $poErr = "Please enter only a number for P.O. Box.";
        } 
        if (!preg_match("([0-9]{1,} [\s\S]*?)",$address))
        { 
           echo $address = test_input($_POST["address"]);
           echo $addressErr = "Address must be only letters, numbers or one of the following _ - . , : ' \"";             
        }
 }
```

you used `&&` that means if both are empty then and then condition work. or else you need to use `||`. means if any one is empty then it works